# Grand Central Dispatch and unit testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have written a simple test case that follows Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_semaphore_signal.3.html) and I am not seeing the results that I'm expecting.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)testExample2
{
    NSLog(@"1");

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0); 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"3");
             dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });

    NSLog(@"2");
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"4");    
    dispatch_release(semaphore);    
}
```

I would expect to read: 1, 2, 3, 4 but instead my console just shows me 1, 3.

I've been able to work around the issue using `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` in a while loop together with a NSLoop hack but the code above should kind of work... right?

Cheers...

**UPDATE**

I just realised that I should be using a separate queue rather than `dispatch_main_queue()`

Comment: Please close your question if you think that it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following in my `tearDown`.

```
while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
    NSLog(@"...Tearing Down Tests..");
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                             beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
}
dispatch_release(semaphore);
```

and pushing the semaphore creation into the `setUp`.